# Cython-compiled *.pyd causes python interpreter to crash

Tags: python, windows-7, cython

I am compiling some modules with Cython into *.pyd files that get imported by a Python program. I have tested all of my modules and they all work with the Python program. At least, they all worked until today, when I tried to run the program and the interpreter crashed upon trying to load one of the *.pyd files.  It crashed with the Windows message "python.exe has stopped working".  I have been able to identify the *.pyd file that causes this, because by removing it I can start up my program. Cython is still able to compile this file just fine, and there have been no source code changes since yesterday, when it was still working. I have searched for about two hours on issues relating to this problem, but I still have no idea what I'm working with here. Might anybody have an idea what's going on?

I have Python 2.7 (32-bit) installed on Windows 7.

Comment: You've changed __something__ since yesterday. You need to show us enough that we can figure out what that is if you want a useful answer to your question.

Comment: Were there any automatic Windows updates during the night?

Comment: @agf - I haven't touched this overnight. It doesn't have to necessarily be anything changed within the program, it could very well be a system change (like Windows Update as Ethan suggests). This really is all I can show you.

Comment: @Ethan - There was an optional update this morning at 8:18 AM. It is KB2310138 (Definition 1.111.35.0). I can't imagine that this would cause any problems with my program, but it's worth investigating...

Comment: Have you tried removing bits of the problematic module to isolate the bit that causes the crash?

Comment: Thanks for the responses guys. I restarted my machine a second time and the program is successfully working. I hope that it was just that I needed to restart my machine after the update had finished. Thanks!