# Cython crashing python

Tags: python, cython

When i attempt to run a .pyd or .pyx file python crashes. Even the simplest case causes the error.

helloworld.pyx

```
print("hello world")
```

setup.py

```
from distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize

setup(ext_modules = cythonize("helloworld.pyx"))
```

Running setup.py successfully compiles the helloworld.pyd file. However upon importing the file in python it crashes after printing "hello world".

Using `pyximport` causes the same behavior.

System info: OS: Windows 7; Compiler: TMD-GCC-64, gcc version 5.1.0; Python: Python 3.4.3, Anaconda 2.2.0 (64 bit);

Comment: What error? What output on crash? What version of Cython ([it can be relevant as here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20425936/cython-crash-from-documentation-example)) do you use?

Comment: @John_West I dont get an error code. Only a window stating that python.exe has crashed.

Comment: [See also](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7094158/1566267)

Comment: @John_West I tried restarting. No dice.

Comment: This seems revelant http://stackoverflow.com/a/29376707/1566267 Try to change python version (to 2.7). The question seems to be popular on software forums, maybe a deeper search through them could reveal the problem